# How to set list padding / margin responsively

Tags: html, css

This doesn't come up much for standard bullet lists, but for Roman numerals the numeral width can vary a lot from one `<li>` to another.

Ex: II vs XVII

I'm having a hard time setting enough padding for lists so that wide "bullets" don't get clipped and narrow bullets don't get awkwardly indented for no reason.

Basically I'm looking for a CSS solution to achieve the minimum left spacing so that bullets / numerals never get clipped.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand the issue. Could you please share an example or try to explain better? I don't see the issue with roman numeral bulleting (as shown here) http://jsfiddle.net/CG3bD/

Answer (score 1):

Your concerns regarding awkward indenting are valid. But this is the nature of ordered lists.
But you can avoid the clipping issue by using this css declaration.

```
li {
    list-style-position: inside;
}
```

This declaration should keep anything from getting clipped, but depending on the length of the numeral, the content of your list item is going to be further in.

Comment: Thanks. This looks like what I want. Do you know anything about the X-browser support for this?

Comment: [W3Schools : list-style-position](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_list-style-position.asp)

Answer (score -1):

Not sure this is what you're asking for w/o an example, but try this:

```
li {
    list-style: upper-roman;
    margin: 0 0 0 2em ;
}
```

Change 2em to whatever you want. [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nicoleamurray/WFPtP/).